# Catch UnhandledExceptions raised on Threads, Tasks, Timers, ThreadPool threads, and BackgroundWorkers

Tags: wpf, multithreading, c#-4.0, unhandled-exception

I have a WPF C# 4.0 application that I'm using to investigate unhandled exception handling.  I would like to have just one place in my code that handles unhandled exceptions raised on any thread no matter how the thread was created.In my App.xaml.cs file, I have these unhandled exception handlers that spit out messages to the console:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += this.CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += this.Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;
    }

    void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Current_DispatcherUnhandledException");
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CurrentDomain_UnhandledException");
    }
}
```

I have a single WPF window with five buttons on it that start threads in five different ways: Task, Thread, ThreadPool, BackgroundWorker, and System.Threading.Timer.  The code for each button click starts a new task, thread, etc. respectively and throws a NotImplementedException on the new thread.  In some cases the exception is caught, in others, the exception is not caught.

Here are my click handlers with code comments that show whether the exception thrown on that thread is caught:

```
private void Button_Task_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); //not caught
        });
}

private void Button_Thread_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(
        new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart((x) =>
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            //CurrentDomain_UnhandledException caught
        }));
    thread.Start();
}

private void Button_ThreadPool_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        new System.Threading.WaitCallback((x) =>
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            //CurrentDomain_UnhandledException caught
        }));
}

private void Button_BWorker_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bg = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    bg.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
    bg.RunWorkerAsync();
}
private void bg_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); //not caught
}

private void Button_Timer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((x) =>
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            //CurrentDomain_UnhandledException caught
        }, null, 0, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

This behavior seems inconsistent to me.Why do Timers, Thread objects, and ThreadPool threads catch the exception whereas BackgroundWorkers and Tasks don't? I use mostly Tasks, Timers, and BackgroundWorkers in my code, so I experience this inconsistency.Does the MSDN have some documentation that explains how WPF handles unhandled exceptions on threads created in these five different ways?

Edit:  I tried a sixth thread creation method using Action.BeginInvoke().  This appears to act similarly to a Task.  The code is here:

```
private void Button_Action_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Action action = () =>
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            //not caught
        };
    action.BeginInvoke(this.DoNothing, null);
}
private void DoNothing(object arg) { }
```

Edit #2: I looked at parallel loops that throw exceptions.  It looks like any exception that is raised in the two parallel loops below will be caught:

```
private void Button_AsParallel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const int loops = 20;
    var list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
    {
        list.Add(i);
    }

    foreach (var item in list.AsParallel().Select(s => s))
    {
        if (item == 15)
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            //CurrentDomain_UnhandledException caught
    }
}

private void Button_ParallelFor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const int loops = 100;
    var list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
    {
        list.Add(i);
    }

    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, loops, (int i) =>
        {
            if (list[i] == 90)
                throw new NotImplementedException();
                //CurrentDomain_UnhandledException caught
        });
}
```

Comment: For BackgroundWorkers, I know that I can inspect the e.Error property available in RunWorkerCompleted.  From there I can re-throw the exception.  I'm still surprised that the UnhandledException handler I have doesn't handle this.  Also, I learned about the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException for exceptions raised in a Task.  I cannot get this to work.

Comment: You have that backwards.  Thread, timer and threadpool do *not* catch the exception.  Which is why you can see them when the unhandled exception terminates the application.

The Task and BackgroundWorker classes are wrappers that are supposed to make dealing with exceptions *easier* so errors in their code do *not* terminate the application.  You just forgot to write the code to actually check if an exception was raised.  So they go un-observed.  A task doesn't raise the exception until you obtain the result.  A BGW passes the exception with the e.Error property in the RunWorkerCompleted event

Comment: For Tasks, it looks like I have to make a call to task.Wait() in order to ensure that the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException event happens.  In my quick testing, if I don't call task.Wait(), TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException doesn't happen.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around more and testing, here is how I will handle exceptions raised on other threads.  For unhandled exceptions, ensure that I make the following call at the top of Application.OnStartup():

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
    this.CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

For creating threads, I'll prefer to use `System.Threading.Thread`, `System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, or `System.Threading.Timer`.  I find `BackgroundWorker`s useful, so I extended the class in a way that will make it easier to handle unhandled exceptions:

```
public class MyBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
{
    protected override void OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            throw e.Error;
        else
            base.OnRunWorkerCompleted(e);
    }
}
```

I can use `IEnumerable.AsParallel` or `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For` for parallel loops because the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException will catch their exceptions as well.

I will avoid `Tasks`.  I will also avoid `Action<T>`s, and `Func<T>`s if I call `BeginInvoke` on them.  I'll avoid these because `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` does *not* catch their exceptions.